# Satellite view photos returned from javascript api calls are older that those seen on Google Maps web site

Tags: image, satellite

I have noticed that the satellite view returned by the js API V3 for a given location is older than the image set seen on the Google web site for the same location. My assumption is based on the fact that in the API image there is a green field whereas on Google maps site there are new houses.

Anything I can do to make sure that latest images are returned by the API calls?

Comment: How did you implement the API? We need Code to look at.

Comment: Perhaps my question somehow got to the wrong forum. I didn't implement an API ... I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API v3 ... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ ... referenced in my web app as https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&sensor=false (replaced my actual key with Xs).

Comment: function mapLocation(latitude, longitude) {
    $("#MapPanel").modal({}); // show the map
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: location,
        zoom: 19,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MapCanvas"), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: location
    });
}